# Pass Model for Partial View to _Layout.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to show the total number of items in a shopping cart, so my plan was to add a Partial View to the footer in the shared file: _Layout.cs, like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PartialViewShoppingCartStatus.cshtml", Model)
```

But then I got a red line below it and I realized that there was no model passed from a Action method in a Controller. So how can I solve this? There isn't any Controller for the _Layout.cs! Perhaps there are other and better solutions?

Comment: One options would be to assign the value to a `ViewBag` property and use `@Html.Partial("..", ViewBag.ItemCount)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke OK, Thanks I try...

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for my stupid question, but what should I replace the ".." with?

Comment: Dude u can do it without the partial view and if u do making than ".." replace by your partial view link

Comment: @front-back ".." would be the name of the partial view

Comment: What you have written in your code (`~/Views/Shared/PartialViewShoppingCartStatus.cshtml`). And since you passing an `int`, then I assume the model in that partial is `@model int`. But why are you putting this the `_Layout.cshtml` Do you really need that footer in every single page?

Comment: Thanks all of you, but I solved it like this: I replaced the Model with the Session that holds the content for the shopping cart and its Model. Good or bad?

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way of doing this is creating a DTO(Data Transfer Object) wich contains all the models and properties you want to pass from the Controller to the View. You can only sent one model from the Controller to the View, but that model can contain instances of other models. Some more information can be found on the [asp.net website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5). You could use a ViewBag but I don't like it very much.

So in the View You would get something like this:

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/PartialViewShoppingCartStatus.cshtml", MyDto.Model2)
```

And in the controller you want to send somehting like this:

```
class Model1
{
    string title {get;set;}
}

class Model2 
{
    string name {get;set;}
}

class MyDto 
{
    MyModel1 = new Model1();
    MyModel2 = new Model2();
}
```

Hope this helps

PS: If you do choose to work with DTO's I think it is a good idea to look at something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) as well to keep your code cleaner.

Answer (score -1):

In controller make a count with query and do pass that into `ViewData["Total"] = count;` and do show that into your cshtml by `@ViewData["Total"]`